# Создание рандомного файла

Tags: linux, bash, безопасность

Собственно, нужно создать большой по размеру(~100mb) файл, с рандомными символами. Желательно сделать это средствами системы и максимально просто. Есть идеи?

Comment: Например, `dd if=/dev/urandom of=имя_файла bs=100M count=1`. [Вот ответ про это на enSO](https://superuser.com/a/470957/734823).

Comment: Уже пробовал так, в итоге я не могу ченкуть сам файл, посмотреть что у него внутри.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно записать ~10<sup>8</sup> случайных байт из `/dev/urandom`

```
head -c 100000000 /dev/urandom > file
```

Или вот так:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=file bs=100M count=1 iflag=fullblock
```

Можно записать только печатные символы как-то так:

```
tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9~!@#$%^&*_-' < /dev/urandom | head -c 100M > file
```

Можно и [по совету](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/678114/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0/678118#comment992177_678118) использовать base64:

```
base64 < /dev/urandom | head -c 100M > file
```

Вроде при таком подходе это будет столь же безопасно (никакой конец обрезать не надо), но даст меньший набор печатных символов.

Comment: Хм, сейчас попробую

Comment: можно использовать `base64` для более «экономичного» получения печатных ascii-символов из набора байт. только последние несколько байт вывода программы лучше отрезать — они весьма «неслучайны».

Comment: Почему `urandom`, а не `random`?

Comment: @Qwertiy Из random очень долго ждать 100M.

Comment: Я думал, наоборот... А почему так?

Comment: @Qwertiy если коротко, то ответ есть даже [тут](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random_и_/dev/urandom)

Comment: Ясно, я их перепутал...

Answer (score -1):

Если задача именно создать "заглушку" то есть уже готовое решение в util-linux

```
~$ fallocate --help

Usage:
 fallocate [options] <filename>

Preallocate space to, or deallocate space from a file.

Options:
 -c, --collapse-range remove a range from the file
 -d, --dig-holes      detect zeroes and replace with holes
 -l, --length <num>   length for range operations, in bytes
 -n, --keep-size      maintain the apparent size of the file
 -o, --offset <num>   offset for range operations, in bytes
 -p, --punch-hole     replace a range with a hole (implies -n)
 -z, --zero-range     zero and ensure allocation of a range
 -v, --verbose        verbose mode

 -h, --help     display this help and exit
 -V, --version  output version information and exit

For more details see fallocate(1).
```

Comment: боюсь, содержимое файла, полученное этой командной, будет отнюдь не случайным